# Chop() is chopping more than what is asked

Tags: php, string, chop

I have multiple random strings, and I'm trying to pull `"SpottedBlanket"` out of the string. Some of them work fine:

```
DarkBaySpottedBlanket --
DarkBay

BaySpottedBlanket --
Bay
```

but others are cutting out more than it should.

```
RedRoanSpottedBlanket --
RedR

BlackSpottedBlanket --
Blac

DunSpottedBlanket --
Du
```

this is the code I'm using, but I thought it would be self explanatory:

```
 $AppyShortcut = chop($AppyColor,"SpottedBlanket");
```

`$AppyColor` would obviously be the random generated string. Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chop` function takes the string in the second argument - which in this case is `"SpottedBlanket"`, and removes any contiguous characters that it finds from the right hand side.

So for the case of `"RedRoanSpottedBlanket"`, you'd get back `"RedR"` because `"o"`, `"a"`, and `"n"` are letters that can be found in the string `"SpottedBlanket"`.

`chop()` is usually used to remove trailing white space - a way of cleaning user input before performing some action on it.

Give your array:

```php
$strings = ["DarkBaySpottedBlanket", "RedRoanSpottedBlanket", "BlackSpottedBlanket", "DunSpottedBlanket"];
```

What you might be looking for is somerthing like this:

```php
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  print substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "SpottedBlanket")) . "\n";
}
```

This finds the position of the string from the end using `strrpos()`, then returns the start of the string until that position, using `substr()`.